# Rest API methods with same URL

Tags: spring, rest, http, get

I have 2 GET REST methods as given below in a class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test/server", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public void getServer() {
  ....
}


@RequestMapping(value = "test/{key}", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public void getTestPathVariable(@PathVariable("key") final String key) {
 ....
}
```

when I consume the rest api with URL "http://localhost:8080/test/server". It always calls the getServer() method. 
I am wondering why it does not create an ambiquity as the URL is valid for both getServer() and getTestPathVariable() method. Please help me to understand.